# oracle database cannot run on kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, oracle11g

I use local docker image and deploy oracle database to kubernetes from .yaml file with StatefulSet.

The image is 100GB , after running with kubectl apply -f file.yaml , database is mounted and when finish the installation the container is shutting down  and the pod create new container with same result and so on.

If i run the container from docker with docker run ..... the container work and i can enter and use the database , only in k8s cluster get the problem , Its tested from 3 computers , local and on cloud(eks) the result is the same.

Dockerfile is :
`CMD exec  $ORACLE_HOME/startup.sh`

startup.sh file is:

```
sqlplus SYS/SYS as sysdba <<EOF
   startup
   exit
EOF
/bin/bash
```

In the logs i see starting up and then finished the exit; command and pod instance crashed:
`Database mounted. ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel Process ID: 124 Session ID: 261 Serial number:23381 SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production`

I expect someone to give me advice.

Comment: I would say that is kind of expected: since there is no tty, bash process exits immediately which causes container to shutdown. The dirty hack is to replace last `/bin/bash` with `sleep infinity`, however that is worth to think about how to make it more robust and reliable, take official Oracle docker image for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the command execution.
Container will stop as soon as your startup process is finished.
You'll be required to run your process forever.
If it's a http server,then it'll run forever.
So it's better to start the main service or you can put

```
command: ["sleep","infinity"]
```

In your container spec inside your deployment yaml.
Please refer this
https://devopscube.com/keep-docker-container-running/